# Reverse text in python function

Tags: python, string, list, error-handling, indexing

I am trying to manually (without the built in function) reverse a string of text, however the code gives me a "list assignment index out of range" for `list_rev[u] = list_[i]`. I don't understand why that happens? What I am trying to do is take the text from the `list_` and place it in `list_rev` in a reverse order and then print `list_rev`.

Thanks!

```
text = raw_input("Word?")

text = str(text)

def reverse(text):
    list_rev = []
    list_ = []
    length = int(len(text))
    k = 0
    while k < (length):
        list_.append(str(text)[k])
        k += 1

    i = int(length-1)
    u = 0
    while i >= 0:
        list_rev[u] = list_[i]
        u += 1
        i -= 1
    return list_rev,

print reverse(text)
```

Comment: `my_string = "foo bar baz"; reversed_string = my_string[::-1]`

Comment: you need to append to list_rev, it is of size 0 and you never change its size. apart from that, this is horrendous code for too many reasons....

Answer (score 1):

You receive the error "list assignment index out of range" from the expression `list_rev[u]` because the index (`u`) is outside the range `0 .. len(list_rev)-1`. In particular, `list_rev` is empty, so there are no possible values of `u` that refer to a valid element of `list_rev`.

If you want to add a *new* element to list_rev, try `.append()`, `.extend()`, or `.insert()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can append characters to the list:

```
text = raw_input("Word?")

text = str(text)

def reverse(text):
    list_rev = []
    list_ = []
    length = int(len(text))
    k = 0
    while k < (length):
        list_.append(str(text)[k])
        k += 1

    i = int(length-1)
    u = 0
    while i >= 0:
        list_rev.append(list_[i])
        i -= 1
    return list_rev,

print reverse(text)
```

Output:

```
Word?qwerty
(['y', 't', 'r', 'e', 'w', 'q'],)
```

Answer (score 0):

list_rev is an empty list : you have to append the char :

```
text = raw_input("Word?")

text = str(text)

def reverse(text):
    list_rev = []
    list_ = []
    length = int(len(text))
    k = 0
    while k < (length):
        list_.append(str(text)[k])
        k += 1

    i = int(length-1)
    u = 0
    while i >= 0:
        list_rev.append(  list_[i] )
        u += 1
        i -= 1
    return list_rev

print ''.join(  str(elem) for elem in reverse(text) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply solve this as below using insert,

```
def reverse(text):
    reverse_list = []
    for a in text:
        reverse_list.insert(0,a)
    return "".join(reverse_list)

text = raw_input("Word?")

reverse_text = reverse(text)

print reverse_text
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using strings;

```
def reverse(text):
  reversed = ''
  for index in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
    reversed += text[index]
  return reversed
```